# Seeking book or site for help with ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, references

I am new to the field of GIS and use Trimble Pathfinder and TerraSync.

I just started with ArcGIS 10.3 and was wondering if anyone can recommend a entry level "Q&A" book or site for ArcGIS 10?